# KendoUI formatting date and time field

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to turn a previously date only field to a date-time field but it is not working.

I have:

```
schema: {
    model: {
    id: 'id',
    fields: {
        dateCreated: {
        type: "date", format: "{0:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm}", editable: "false"
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work, the date comes out formatted properly but the time ends up being 00:00.

If I change the field type to "string" the data shows properly but is formatted the SQL way i.e:

```
2012-05-11 12:56:29
```

There is no such field type as "datetime", only "date". How do I get this to output how I want? i.e:

```
11/05/2012 12:56
```

---

Any one have any ideas?

Answer (score 24):

You must use a template `'#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(dateCreated), 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt')#'`

Answer (score 8):

Where are you trying to use this data?  If you're using it in a grid, you can use the 'template' property in the column definition

```
var columnDefinition = [
    {
        field: "dateCreated",
        title: "Created",
        template: "#= kendo.toString(dateCreated,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt') #"
    }
];
```

[Here's a fiddle with the formatting in a grid](http://jsfiddle.net/schapman/Pm4y3/)

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work :( I ended up preformatting my date in the SQL that brought the date out using DATE_FORMAT.